# String interpolation update after change

Tags: ruby, setter, string-interpolation, attr-accessor

I have values in an interpolated string that refer to an array like this:

```
attr_accessor :s, :gamespace

def initialize
  @s = [1,2,3]
  @gamespace = "#{@s[0]} | #{@s[1]} | #{@s[2]} "
end
```

When I change the value of `@s`, it doesn't update the value of `@gamespace`.

I resorted to making an additional method like this:

```
def gamespace
  @gamespace = "#{@s[0]} | #{@s[1]} | #{@s[2]}"
end
```

and then I call it after any change to `@s`.

Is there a way to let `attr_accessor` update the string interpolation after a change without writing this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reader method only refers to an instance variable, it doesn't re-evaluate it. If you want to use a reader method to get an updated value, the only thing you can do is to not use the default setter method, but write your own.

```
def s= a
  @s = a
  @gamespace = "#{a[0]} | #{a[1]} | #{a[2]} "
end
```

Setting `@a` should not be done directly, but should always be done through `s=`. This applies to `initialize` as well:

```
def initialize; s=([1, 2, 3]) end
```

Comment: That's what I figured, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

When you change your `@s` array, then you will need to re-create the `gamespace` string. Or you have to write a setter method instead of the `attr_accessor`. But from your example it looks like there is no need for the `@gamespace` variable at all:

```
attr_accessor :s

def initialize(s = [1,2,3])
  @s = s
end

def gamespace
  @s.join(' | ')
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternate solution but there is reason for the other gamespace attribute. Recreating is key but it seems this is not possible without writing the setter method as I did.